# How to concat before image format in java

Tags: java

I will have a String name as

```
String name = "Test.jpg"
```

Or

```
 String name = "Test.png"

 String name = "Test.jpeg"

 String name = "Test.gif"
```

I am  appending a unique id to the name

as shown below

```
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
      int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
             name = name+randomInt;
                System.out.println(name);
```

With this the file name looks as

```
Test.jpg86
```

how can i make it look as

```
Test_86.jpg
```

could anybody please let me know how to append after image

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider possibility of more dots occurring before the extension for a fully robust solution. String.split() solutions assume exactly one dot.

- Use regex to find last portion via Pattern/Matcher.
- Test if filename actually contains a dot
- Use String.format() to build name, you could use %04d for a nice padded name, e.g. Test_0028.jpg etc.

Example

```
String name = "Test.foo.bar.jpg";

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\.(.*?)").matcher(name);
if (matcher.matches()) {  // <== test input filename is OK?
    System.out.println(String.format("%s_%d.%s", matcher.group(1), randomInt, matcher.group(2)));
}
```

Output

```
Test.foo.bar_28.jpg
```

Splitting is already solved by Apache Commons IO class [FilenameUtils.getExtension()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

It is unbelievable that people are suggesting using regular expressions and third-party libraries for something so simple:

```
int period = name.lastIndexOf('.');
name = name.substring(0, period) + "_" + randomInt + name.substring(period);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
String name = "Test.jpg"

String format[] = name.split(".");

String finalName = format[0] + "_" + randomInt + format[1]
```

Comment: This is wrong - a dot matches any character, i.e. the result will be "T_XXe". You must escape the dot with double backslash (see other answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split`:

```
    String[] nameSplit = name.split("\\.");
    String newName = nameSplit[0] + randomInt + "." + nameSplit[1];
```

Take into account that `split(".")` will not work as `split` takes regex as argument and "." matches any single character

Comment: Why \\. and not a single .?

Comment: @committedandroider a single backslash will not compile. First "\" is to escape the second one, which is part of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
   String[] imageArray=imageName.split(\\".");
   String newImageName= imageArray[0]+"_"+ID+"."+imageArray[1];
```

Split the image with . and append the type to first part and concate all the three..

ID must be string and the image name must not contain any . in the name else you will have to iterate of the array size and would have to append in the second last element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is not more than 1 dot in the name:

```
    String[] split = name.split("\\.", 2);

    if (split.length > 1) {
        String result = split[0] + "_" + randomInt + "." + split[1];
    }
```

If there may be more dots in the name, use a matcher:

```
    String name = "abc.def.ghi.jpg";
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomInt = random.nextInt(100);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\.([^.]*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String result = m.group(1) + "_" + randomInt + "." + m.group(2);
        System.out.println(result); // abc.def.ghi_61.jpg
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
name = name.replace(".",("_" + randomInt + "."));
```

Or if the `name` contains more then one `.`:

```
String extension = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."),name.length());
name = name.replace(extension,("_" + randomInt + extension));
```